# vue.js - watch when disabled element and return data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two style sheets, light and dark themes, with dark disabled by default.
When clicking on a button, this toggles the themes (activating one when disabling the other) and this works well.

Now I want a function that can monitor when the #themelight stylesheet is disabled and return { themeLight: false } in the data (that will later be used with some "v-if" in the template). It probably needs to be watched as any changes in the #themelight need to be reflected in the data again.

My code seems wrong

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themelight.css" id="themelight">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themedark.css" id="themedark" disabled>
</head>

<body>
    <button v-on:click="themeToggle"></button>
</body>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            themeLight: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
    themeToggle() {
        document.querySelector('#themelight').toggleAttribute('disabled');
        document.querySelector('#themedark').toggleAttribute('disabled');
    },
        currentTheme() {
            document.querySelector("#themelight");
            addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                if (event.target.disabled) {
                    this.themeLight = false;
                } else {
                    this.themeLight = true;
                }
            });
        }
    },
    watch: {
            themeLight() {
                this.currentTheme();
        }
      },
    created() {
        this.currentTheme();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't actually understand what you asked, can you please be more specific about the problem

Comment: I want a function that can monitor when the #themelight stylesheet is disabled and return { themeLight: false } in the data.
It probably needs to be watched as any changes in the #themelight need to be reflected in the data again.
Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: can you show me the other part of code with the button ? (as you have mentioned above)

Comment: I edited the code!

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using Vue.js then try to avoid the vanilla javascript by that i mean you should not use the `document.querySelector` etc..

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themedark.css" :disabled="themeLight">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themelight.css" :disabled="!themeLight">
</head>

<body>
    <button @click="themeToggle"></button>
</body>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        themeLight: true
    }),
    methods: {
        themeToggle() {
            this.themeLight = !this.themeLight
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now you do not need to monitor changed in the `themeLight` variable since you are changing it yourself on the button click
If the above code do not works than notify me, i have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems weird to me, but you can use computed property.

```
  computed: {
    themeLight: function () {
        return window.themeLight.disabled
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhance your watch method and prevent it to be blocked for infinite loop.
It is a good practice to compare newValue with the oldValue.

```
watch: {
    themeLight(newValue, oldValue) {
         if(newValue && newValue!=oldValue) {
            this.currentTheme();
         }
    }
}
```